# htaccess Redirect to Categories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need an htaccess code that turns:

```
site.com/category/example
```

to

```
site.com/list.php?catID=example
```

how can I do that?

I also need:

```
site.com/read/today
```

to

```
site.com/show.php?id=today
```

Please help me. I've got a few things but couldn't make it work for me. Here is what I got:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ $1/anasayfa [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ sitegoster.php?id=$1&kayit_id=$2 [L,NC]
```

Tried to modify these but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following rules:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ list.php?catID=$1 [L, NC]
RewriteRule ^read/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ show.php?id=$1 [L, NC]
```

Comment: I didn't get any errors with my previous tries. But this one gave 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: What now? If still doesn't work, wait till tomorrow (today). It's too late to think for me now.

Comment: still nothing. I've checked httpd.conf etc. all correct. still nothing. I'll keep searching thanks for your help

Comment: I've no idea what was the problem. Now it works thanks again.